# Password field not validated unless

Tags: imacros

The passwords couldn't be validated. I have to select on the password field and then click on other field for validation. Otherwise, I can't submit the form. Somehow the javascript validation must detect a out-of-focus thing. The validation will also be true if I just press the arrow right.

```
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=ID:password1 CONTENT=1000!Hello
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=ID:password2 CONTENT=1000!Hello

###what should I put here (in-between) to emulate a keyboard tab or "focus then out-of-focus" (jump to other field)?###

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=ID:password-submit
TAG POS=4 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=*
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try event recording mode, you can emulate the arrow right key. Read more [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVENT).